# Реализация функции

Tags: php

**Есть функция**

```
function form_add($type, $name, $class = "", $id = "", $value = "")
{
    $class = strlen($class) > 0 ? "class='$class'" : 0;
    $id = strlen($id) > 0 ? "id='$id'" : 0;
    $value = strlen($value) > 0 ? "value='$value'" : 0;

    $form = "<input $class $id $value type='$type' name='$name' />";

    return $form;
}
```

форма
    `echo form_add('text','name');`

хотелось бы.так

```
echo form_add('type'=>'text', 'name'=>'name');
```

Как реализовать?

Comment: Обычно это делать не рекомендуется. Лучше оставить как есть

Comment: Только уберите атрибуты `0` из результата. =)

Answer (score 1):

Можно запилить что-то вроде этого:

```
function domSelfClosedElement($name, array $attrs = []) {
  $attrs = array_map(function($val, $key) { 
      return htmlspecialchars($key).'="'.htmlspecialchars($val).'"';
  }, array_values($attrs), array_keys($attrs));
  $attrs = implode(' ', $attrs);

  return "<$name $attrs/>";
}

echo domSelfClosedElement("input", ['name' => 'username', 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control']);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function form_add($array, $class = "", $id = "", $value = "")
{
$class = strlen($class) > 0 ? "class='$class'" : 0;
$id = strlen($id) > 0 ? "id='$id'" : 0;
$value = strlen($value) > 0 ? "value='$value'" : 0;

$form = "<input $class $id $value type='".$array['type']."' name='".$array['type']."' />";

return $form;
} 
echo form_add(['type' => 'text', 'name' => 'name']);
```

Comment: Dizzy221, спасибо) если убрать $class = strlen($class) > 0 ? "class='$class'" : 0; то можно будет так? form_add('class'=>'blue_form');